# outlook startup code does not work

Tags: vba, outlook

I have got this code in "ThisOutlookSession"

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInspectors = Outlook.Inspectors
Dim oNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set oNamespace = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 MsgBox ("startup works")
```

and then quite a lot of code....

But it does not start, I do not get the msgbox "startup works" at all. If I start the Sub manually with F5, everything goes fine.

Any ideas, why this does not work?

Thanks
Max

Answer (score 0):

Appears this is unusual:

```
Set oNamespace = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

Try:

```
Set oNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```